# Why UIButton's title content is abbreviated after calling [sizeToFit]?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I tried to fit UIButton to its title text by calling `[SizeToFit]`. Unfortunately, I got unwanted result as the following.

[image]

I suppose that the button's size is smaller than its title size. therefore, the title string was abbreviated. The simple and silly solution I chose was plus 20pt to its width after calling `[sizeToFit]`.

I believe that there is any solution better than I used.
Is there anybody who know it?

Comment: are you using auto layout to constraint the button width?

Comment: @WubaoLi No, I use not auto layout feature but auto resizing for supporting iOS5. I only set flexible width to the button. But, I don't think it is not relative to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeToFit` does not resize the text but it is used to resize the view so it encloses its subviews. Please use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` instead to resize font size to fit your button width.

```
btnMyButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Or if you want to resize your button to fit the width of your font, here is how you can do that too:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:btnMyButton.titleLabel.font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
CGFloat buttonWidth = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:btnMyButton.titleLabel.text attributes:attributes] size].width;

CGRect frame = btnMyButton.frame;
btnMyButton.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, buttonWidth, frame.size.width);
```

EDIT:

`buttonWidth` does give you the width your title requires to fit in, however if its still not working then please can you verify that:

1) Your button does not have any margins set, if it does then you might want to add those to your `buttonWidth` variable before setting `btnMyButton.frame` as:

```
buttonWidth += 10; //assuming you have 10pt margins.
```

2) Your button is not getting shrunk via an `AutoLayout` constraint or `AutoResizingMask`.

3) Your button is not getting font, size, or title set after `btnMyButton.frame` has been set.

4) Your button has enough room to resize.

Comment: Thank a lot. I came to know resizing font automatically fitted in its container. Unfortunately, your suggestions did not solve my problem.  I don't want to shrink. And, second suggestion still made a ellipsis too.